# ValueError exception when passing verify=False to post

Tags: python-requests

Forgive my ignorance, I'm just starting to use the Python requests module, with version 2.22.0. When I pass a request with `verify=False`, I get an exception. Is there something I need to set the right knob in urllib3? Is this a case where I need to use a transport adapter? Thanks!

Request:

```
response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers, verify=False, auth=('user','pass'))
```

Exception:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 116, in post

    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request

    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request

    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send

    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send

    timeout=timeout

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen

    chunked=chunked,

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request

    self._validate_conn(conn)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 994, in _validate_conn

    conn.connect()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 374, in connect

    context.verify_mode = resolve_cert_reqs(self.cert_reqs)

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 443, in verify_mode

    super(SSLContext, SSLContext).verify_mode.__set__(self, value)

ValueError: Cannot set verify_mode to CERT_NONE when check_hostname is enabled.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to create a session :

```
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_ import ssl

class SSLContextAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = ssl.create_default_context()
        kwargs['ssl_context'] = context
        context.load_default_certs() # this loads the OS defaults on Windows
        return super(SSLContextAdapter, self).init_poolmanager(*args, **kwargs)

s = requests.Session()
adapter = SSLContextAdapter()
s.mount('yoururl', adapter)
response = s.post('yoururl', data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers, auth=('user','pass'))
```